# Best Removable Glue for Gluing Metal Towel Bar to Stone

Tags: bathroom, adhesive, granite

I rent an apartment where half of the walls of my bathroom are made out of a beautifully finished granite.

This looks nice, but when it comes to hanging my chrome-plated towel bar, there have been some issues.

- I do not want to drill into the granite, since I will want to cleanly remove the towel bar when I move out.
- I think that gluing the towel bar onto the stone is my best option.
- I have tried several glues in the past, but none have worked out well so far.
- Gorilla glue is strong but is difficult to remove cleanly.
- Silicone adhesives seem to work for awhile but the towel bar eventually falls off.

What is the best adhesive to glue chrome-plated metal to finished granite to bear the load of two wet towels yet still allow me to remove it cleanly when I move?

Answer (score 3):

You can use 3M Command Strips. You just need the strips themselves, and not the hook. Attach one side to the bracket and the other to the granite. When you move out, just pull down on the strip to remove.

Depending on the size, some of the strip may be visible. You may be able to trim it to size though.

Comment: I have heard of these things but I had no idea they are so strong - we'll see if they can holdup to a couple of wet towels...

Comment: @William they come in different sizes and strengths, so you can definitely find the appropriate strength. I wouldn't do pull ups on the towel bar, but a couple of wet towels is no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a good relationship with the management, then consider asking them if they will approve your making a permanent attachment of a towel bar / grab bar which would stay if and when you move.

A permanent and strong attachment of a towel rack / grab bar into the granite would also serve as a grab bar for those needing it. Twenty years ago I installed a pair of 24" grab bars in our hall bathroom to act as indestructible towel racks to resist the impulsive forces of a strong teenage male. They survived that use and are now used as grab bars by an elderly man who needs steadying due to loss of strength and balance.

Admittedly my taste runs to the functional and this what I've been installing lately. http://www.grabbarspecialists.com/products.php?cat=945